# Power BI Create new Rows from Columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In Power BI, I have a table looks like:

```
Customer; Amount Paid; Pay CCY; Amount Received; Received CCY
   A          10        USD       -20               GBP
   B          50        CAD       -30               USD
   C         100        GBP       -50               CAD
```

I'd like to convert table to:

```
Customer Amount CCY
  A        10   USD
  B        50   CAD
  C       100   GBP
  A       -20   GBP
  B       -30   USD
  C       -50   CAD
```

Is there an easy way?

Comment: You can "duplicate" the table and then concat the rows of original table with the rows of the new one. I can't use PowerBI right now to check the right operations names, but maybe you can figure it out. But I believe there must be a easier way.

Answer (score 0):

In the Query Editor, select the amount columns and click Unpivot Columns under the Transform tab.

The result should look like this:

[image: Unpivoted]

Then you can define a custom column to pick which current to use either based on the Attribute column or the Value column. Then remove the extra columns.

The whole query (pasted from the Advanced Editor) looks something like this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTI0ABKhwS5AUtcIxHZ3ClCK1YlWcgKyTUECzo5gSWOYQpCkM1gnTDlQFq4yNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Customer = _t, #"Amount Paid" = _t, #"Pay CCY" = _t, #"Amount Received" = _t, #"Recieved CCY" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Amount Paid", Int64.Type}, {"Pay CCY", type text}, {"Amount Received", Int64.Type}, {"Recieved CCY", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Customer", "Pay CCY", "Recieved CCY"}, "Attribute", "Amount"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Attribute", Order.Ascending}, {"Customer", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "CCY", each if [Amount] > 0 then [Pay CCY] else [Recieved CCY], type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Pay CCY", "Recieved CCY", "Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment one could just append the tables. I started with this example
[image]

I just appended the table to itself, here is the M -Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblData"]}[Content],
    tblStart1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Customer", type text}, {"Amount Paid", Int64.Type}, {"Pay CCY", type text}, {"Amount Received", Int64.Type}, {"Received CCY", type text}}),
    removeColumns1 = Table.SelectColumns(tblStart1,{"Customer", "Amount Paid", "Pay CCY"}),
    tblLeft = Table.RenameColumns(removeColumns1,{{"Amount Paid", "Amount"}, {"Pay CCY", "CCY"}}),
    tblStart2 = tblStart1,
    removeColumns = Table.SelectColumns(tblStart2,{"Customer", "Amount Received", "Received CCY"}),
    tblRight = Table.RenameColumns(removeColumns,{{"Amount Received", "Amount"}, {"Received CCY", "CCY"}}),
    tblCombine = Table.Combine({tblLeft,tblRight})
in
    tblCombine
```

Result is

[image]